# microsoft edge The required antiforgery cookie is not present while its working in all other browser

Tags: asp.net-core, http-post, microsoft-edge

Whenever i try to login/register on my site on edge its throwing Error :

```
 InvalidOperationException: The required antiforgery cookie "g657dWuGa0Q" 
 is not present.
```

while the same login/register is working on other browser as well. Here is the stack trace

```
    InvalidOperationException: The required antiforgery cookie "g657dWuGa0Q" is not present.
    Microsoft.AspNet.Antiforgery.DefaultAntiforgeryTokenStore.<GetRequestTokensAsync>d__4.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    Microsoft.AspNet.Antiforgery.DefaultAntiforgery.<ValidateRequestAsync>d__9.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Controllers.FilterActionInvoker.<InvokeAuthorizationFilterAsync>d__47.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Controllers.FilterActionInvoker.<InvokeAuthorizationFilterAsync>d__47.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Controllers.FilterActionInvoker.<InvokeAuthorizationFilterAsync>d__47.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Controllers.FilterActionInvoker.<InvokeAsync>d__44.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Infrastructure.MvcRouteHandler.<RouteAsync>d__6.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Routing.InnerAttributeRoute.<RouteAsync>d__10.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    Microsoft.AspNet.Routing.RouteCollection.<RouteAsync>d__9.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    Microsoft.AspNet.Builder.RouterMiddleware.<Invoke>d__4.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.<Invoke>d__18.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.<Invoke>d__18.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.<Invoke>d__18.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.<Invoke>d__18.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.<Invoke>d__18.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.<Invoke>d__18.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.<Invoke>d__18.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.<Invoke>d__18.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler.IISPlatformHandlerMiddleware.<Invoke>d__8.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics.Entity.MigrationsEndPointMiddleware.<Invoke>d__5.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics.Entity.DatabaseErrorPageMiddleware.<Invoke>d__6.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics.Entity.DatabaseErrorPageMiddleware.<Invoke>d__6.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.<Invoke>d__7.MoveNext()
```

I've also verified the __requestVerificationToken as a hidden field and in http header , is present there.

if i remove the [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] decorator from the post method its not throwing the error but its logging me out directly.

Comment: Check that cookies are enabled

Comment: @CalC cookies are enabled

Comment: Try to clear the browser (cookie) history.

Comment: i tried clearing cookies , resetted the browser @ZhiLv-MSFT